# How do i scrape twitter with jsoup when the class names look like garbage

Tags: web, twitter, jsoup

So i want to scrape twitter using java. I did it before with my python project with ease last year because the timeline is encased in a div tag with the id timeline, and each tweet is in a div with id stream-item.

But now, if you use inspect element on twitter you'd see all the class names are garbage, like

`<div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1awozwy r-18u37iz r-dnmrzs">`

It seems to be randomly generated, so how would i be able to locate the tags when using jsoup?

Comment: Scraping the Twitter website is against the terms of service. There are a couple of Java libraries that use the official API you could try instead.